# Why do I get an error when opening a folder in c#?

Tags: asp.net

[image]

I receive the token and authenticate, but it gives a user error and password.

Comment: Most likely because your IIS Application Pool User cannot access file shares and other network resources.

Comment: Your error states that the username and password are unknown.  I'd start with a good set of credentials.

Comment: Yikes. Opening a network share from your IIS, is strongly discouraged by MS.  Think about it for a minute. @Filburt is right. You probably won't be able to accomplish this with normal authentication and IIS settings.  Are you trying to get the authenticated IIS user to authenticate to the network share (re-using those credentials)?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. It's much harder for us to help you this way. Stack Overflow has built-in support to do syntax highlighting for the code text, and you can add extra comments or explanation to show where things go wrong. That's faster for you, too, to just paste the code text rather than needing to grab and edit an screen image.

Answer (score 1):

`LogonUser()` does get an auth ticket for the desired account, but it *does not change the context of the current process*. The process is *still* running as the user configured in IIS, which likely doesn't have any access to the `caneles03` machine.

Specifically, take a look at the [`LogonUser()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera), which says this in just the third sentence:

> You cannot use **LogonUser** to log on to a remote computer.

If you want a web page to access that machine, you either need to configure IIS to always run the web site with a dedicated account that does have the needed access, use [ASP.Net Impersonation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5.aspx), or start a whole new process that runs as the desired user account to access the network share for you.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code, I can see that you are trying something called an "IIS double hop".  Which is blocked by security (for good reasons). You will need to set up a Kerberos trust between your IIS server and the destination server.

Without a Kerberos trust, windows security will block your authentication because it looks like a hacking attempt.

Just so you know what you are getting into, Kerberos trusts are a little complicated, but there is a lot of good information about how to do it, on the internet and StackOverflow.